# Pandas using the previous rank values to filter out current row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

As the title states I am trying to use the previous rank to filter out the current

Here's an example of my starting df:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'rank': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'x': [0, 3, 0, 3, 4, 2],
    'y': [0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 5],
    'z': [1, 3, 1.2, 2.95, 3, 6],
})
print(df)
#    rank  x  y     z
# 0     1  0  0  1.00
# 1     1  3  4  3.00
# 2     2  0  0  1.20
# 3     2  3  4  2.95
# 4     3  4  5  3.00
# 5     3  2  5  6.00
```

Here's what I want the output to be:

```py
output = pd.DataFrame({
    'rank': [1, 1, 2, 3],
    'x': [0, 3, 0, 2],
    'y': [0, 4, 0, 5],
    'z': [1, 3, 1.2, 6],
})
print(output)
#    rank  x  y    z
# 0     1  0  0  1.0
# 1     1  3  4  3.0
# 2     2  0  0  1.2
# 5     3  2  5  6.00
```

Basically what I want to happen is if the previous rank has any rows with x, y (+- 1 both ways) AND z (+- .1) to remove it.

So for the rows rank 1 ANY rows in rank 2 that have any combo of x = (-1-1), y = (-1-1), z= (.9-1.1) OR x = (2-5), y = (3-5), z= (2.9-3.1)  I want it to be removed.

Comment: Shouldn't the last row be kept? The condition on z is not met

Comment: you're right, I forgot to add that

Comment: OK, so I think my solution should work for you, let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky as your need to access the previous group. You can compute the groups using `groupby` first, and then iterate over the elements and perform your check with a custom function:

```
def check_previous_group(rank, d, groups):
    if not rank-1 in groups.groups:
        # check is a previous group exists, else flag all rows False (i.e. not to be dropped)
        return pd.Series(False, index=d1.index)

    else:
        # get previous group (rank-1)
        d_prev = groups.get_group(rank-1)

        # get the absolute difference per row with the whole dataset 
        # of the previous group: abs(d_prev-s)
        # if all differences are within 1/1/0.1 for x/y/z
        # for at least one rows of the previous group
        # then flag the row to be dropped (True)
        return d.apply(lambda s: abs(d_prev-s)[['x', 'y', 'z']].le([1,1,0.1]).all(1).any(), axis=1)

groups = df.groupby('rank')
mask = pd.concat([check_previous_group(rank, d, groups) for rank,d in groups])
df[~mask]
```

output:

```
   rank  x  y    z
0     1  0  0  1.0
1     1  3  4  3.0
2     2  0  0  1.2
5     3  2  5  6.0
```

Comment: can you explain what you're doing in your function. I am kinda lost lol

Comment: @mike_gundy123 I commented the code, let me know if you have question

Comment: okay thanks for the explanation, it definitely helped! One last question, my real data set has extra columns that are not important for comparison. What do with those in the function? Do I just continue to ignore them in the []?

Comment: as my code is only computing a mask, extra columns shouldn't affect the process

Comment: @mike_gundy123 I provided an answer, but this is almost the same ;)